# Implementing PauseIntent and ResumeIntent in SDKv2 for an Alexa Skill

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on a skill that takes some information on a web page and speak it out. I'd like to being able to stop and resume alexa while reading so I added in my interaction model the built-in intent AMAZON.PauseIntent and AMAZON.ResumeIntent, then I added some sample utterances.

My problem start in the lambda function. I can't find examples on how to do it in the latest ASK-SDK release or how to chain the function call to get the result i'd like

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I could not understand exactly what you want to do.

If you want to pause and resume your Alexa skill then it is possible only for audio streaming files. For now, on normal text data, it's not possible!

Many Developers ask for these things which are still not possible in Alexa: https://www.jargon.com/blog/2019/04/top-7-requests-voice-developers-are-asking-the-alexa-team/

Comment: Yes I need stop and pause on normal text. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Sorry to say but For now it's not possible in Alexa. You can use stop intent to stop but pause and resume currently not supported with normal text in Alexa. I hope this information will be useful to you.